# How to display the children under the parent of an xmll file using jquery?

Tags: jquery, xml, listview

I want to display the children tags in a listview. In that listview i'm adding the parent tag as a list-divider.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<page count="89" name="Sample">
  <sections>
    <section count="3" name="Alphabets" order="1">
      <content file="220993.txt" order="1">A</content>
      <content file="220994.txt" order="2">B</content>
      <content file="220995.txt" order="3">C</content>
    </section>
    <section count="5" name="Numbers" order="2">
      <content file="221006.txt" order="4">five</content>
      <content file="221007.txt" order="5">four</content>
      <content file="221008.txt" order="6">three</content>
      <content file="221009.txt" order="7">two</content>
      <content file="221010.txt" order="8">one</content>
    </section>
    <section count="2" name="Names" order="3">
      <content file="221013.txt" order="9">Sam</content>
      <content file="221014.txt" order="10">Sansha</content>
    </section>
  </sections>
</page>
```

Code:

```
$(xml).find('section').each(function () {
                var section = $(this).attr("name");
                var count = $(this).attr('count');
                var order = $(this).attr('order');
                $(this).children().each(function () {
                    var content = $(this).text();

                    var order = $(this).attr("order");
                    var seq = order + '' + $(this).attr('order');

                        $("#section_list").append('<li data-role="list-divider">' + section + '</li>');
                        $("#section_list").append('<li><a href="" class="style1" data-sequence="s' + seq + '" ><h2>' + content + ' </h2></a></li>');    
                        $("#section_list").listview('refresh');

                });
            });
```

If i'm doing like this parent tag is repeating for every children.

Along with the list-divider. I'm the displaying the description about the each item in the listview. But these description is from the related files of the each item. I'm getting the problem when i'm displaying the listview with the list-divider along with description then the listview displays as all the dividers should be combined first and below that list items with description is displaying. How to display the listview properly with description.

http://jsfiddle.net/2YbT5/

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XcqzU/)**

Try this code..

```
$(xml).find('section').each(function () {
  var section = $(this).attr("name");
  var count = $(this).attr('count');
  var order = $(this).attr('order');
  $("#section_list").append('<li data-role="list-divider">' + section + '</li>');
  $(this).find('content ').each(function () {
     var content = $(this).text();
     var order = $(this).attr("order");
     var seq = order + '' + $(this).attr('order');
     $("#section_list").append('<li><a href="" class="style1" data-sequence="s' + seq + '"  ><h2>' + content + ' </h2></a></li>');    
     });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering i have one doubt. I have a some text files in the children tag. That file i want to display as a description in each item http://jsfiddle.net/2YbT5/

Comment: in my fiddle i'm already displaying the text in the children tags  but parent tags are not properly displaying. How it will be displayed properly ?

Comment: $.mobile.activePage.append('<div id="files" style="display: none"></div>'); this line throwing error.

Comment: thank u.. but by using this id="files" i'm displaying the description..can u please suggest me for this..without this how we display ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36455/discussion-between-prabu-parthipan-and-user2384323)